# Max Real numbers in polynomial

Tags: polynomials, infinity

Let $n$ be an odd natural number and

$$P(x) = x^n + ax^2 + b.$$

Is there an option that $P$ would have more than $3$ real roots?

I thought that max of solution will be $n$.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra tells you there are $n$ *complex* solutions, counting multiplicities.  This doesn't imply anything about real solutions, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Its derivative is $P'(x) = nx^{n-1} + 2ax = x(nx^{n-2} + 2a)$, which has two zeroes, namely $x = 0$ and $x = \sqrt[n-2]{2a/n}$. Therefore $P$ can have at most three zeroes.

As for "max of solution will be $n$", it is the case that the maximal number of solutions for a general polynomial equation
$$
x^n + ax^{n-1} + \cdots + bx^2 + cx + d = 0
$$
is $n$, but in this case, you've narrowed it down to a small subset of all such equations (every coefficient except $b$ and $d$ above is set to $0$), and thus there is nothing wrong in the maximal number of solutions beong smaller than $n$.